# How to keep headers fixed in kableExtra

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kableextra

I am creating an Rmarkdown document from an analysis. I am implementing the kableExtra package to format my tables. I want to have my row headers fixed to the top even when you scroll. How can I keep my headers fixed at the top?

From the vignette "Create Awesome HTML Table with knitr::kable and kableExtra" I see that it says "Starting from version 1.1.0, if you have a fixed-height box, the header row is fixed." I have checked that I have the most recent version and this does not appear to be the case. I have also tried the command fixed_thead without success.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

why <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
wont <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
these <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
headers <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
stay <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
fixed <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

table_data <- data.frame(why, wont, these, headers, stay, fixed)

         table_data %>% 
         kable( format = "html") %>% 
         kable_styling(position = "center", full_width = F, bootstrap_options = c("striped","hover"))%>%        
         scroll_box( width = "1000px", height = "200px", fixed_thead = T)
```

Comment: Works for me. Knit it, open it in chrome, check on it and report back. It may not work in the Rstudio window that opens up but it should work in your browser.

Comment: Wow, that's frustrating. Headers are actually fixed when I open the html document that I saved. The table still renders in the plot output on rstudio and in the window that pops up with your knitted document every time you knit, but those headers aren't fixed.

Comment: It is definitely odd, I agree! Glad it works though--I was hoping it was not just a fix on my machine